# Stopwatch - keeping the elapsed time at zero before the start timer onclick handler is clicked

Tags: javascript

Stopwatch - keeping the elapsed time at zero before the start timer onclick handler is clicked

Hi, I have been working on a Javascript stopwatch for an interview test. I have an issue where the timer starts automatically when the browser loads. I have tried editing the add() function's 'if' statement but not having any joy with it. Can anyone help me?

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    milli = 0, seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() { 
    milli += 10;
    if (milli >= 1000) {
        milli = 0;
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds) + "." + (milli > 90 ? milli : "0" + milli);

    timer();
}

function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 10);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00:00";
    milli = 0; seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test Stopwatch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>
                <time>00:00:000:00</time>
            </h1>

            <button id="start">START</button>
            <button id="stop">STOP</button>
            <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
        </section>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You call the timer below your declaration of timer. Remove `timer();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `timer()` call on the root of the javascript file scope so it is invoked automatically.

```js
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 10);
}
timer(); // This starts it automatically. remove it.
```

correct:

```js
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 10);
}
```